# XJC schema parsing error- cannot resolve name to an element declaration

Tags: xjc

Attempting to parse this schema definition:

```
<xsd:element name="GameManifest" type="GameSystemManifest"/>

<xsd:complexType name="entry">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="SystemName" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="FileLocation" type= "xsd:string"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="GameSystemManifest">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="entry"/> <--Error message says problem line is is here.
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

with XJC nets me this error:

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'entry' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
```

I've got no clue what is wrong here.

Edit: Solved this myself after I read this: http://alsdias.blogspot.com/2012/11/cannot-resolve-name-to-type-definition.html

I changed the definition of "GameSystemManifest" so that "entry" is defined inside of it.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Could you please show your fixed xsd. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare an element named entry. You have the complex type declared but not the element.

Declare:

```
<xsd:element name="entry" type="entry"/>
```